# Clean task not found in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle build file and am not able to execute a build. I am working with old code and the code should be built with `1.0-milestone-7` version since other projects use this version.

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'application'

assert gradle.gradleVersion == '1.0-milestone-7'

mainClassName = "my.ClassTest"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

test {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}


c:\work\gradletest\> gradle clean
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'clean' not found in root project 'gradletest'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
```

Anything I forgot?

Comment: The build script is OK. Perhaps you are running the build from the wrong directory.

Comment: I am in ``c:\work\gradletest\>`` and the build file is there called ``gradletest.gradle``. Should it be renamed to ``build.gradle``?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to rename. It's a very good guess that it is the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the filename to `build.gradle` solves the issue. Note that this is the case in `1.0-milestone-7`.